# How can I prevent Mojolicious from character-escaping stash data?

Tags: perl, html-entities, mojolicious

I am trying to send HTML to a template in Mojolicious and am finding that the html is getting replaced with safe strings somewhere along the way.

```
$self->stash(portalHeaderHtml => "<html>");
```

Becomes

```
 &lt;html&gt;
```

In the source

The template:

```
<%= $portalHeaderHtml %>
```

How do I tell it to display HTML and not replace tags?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Mojolicious::Guides::Rendering`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Rendering#Embedded-Perl) suggests using `==` to disable escaping of characters.

> An additional equal sign can be used to disable escaping of the
>   characters <, >, &, ' and " in results from Perl expressions, which is
>   the default to prevent XSS attacks against your application.
>
> ```
> <%== '<p>test</p>' %>
> ```

Proceed with caution.

Comment: Thank you! I could not find that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I searched for this for one hour and `HTML::Entities` wasn't helpful since it was re-escaped anyway.